# How to create a loop with ngfor that has intermittent toolbar buttons

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I have this below.

```html
<div class="btn-toolbar special">
  <button type="button" class="btn mr-2 mb-2" [ngClass]="selectedStyles.includes('bikram') ? 'btn-yb' : 'btn-outline-secondary'" (click)="toggleClass('bikram')">Bikram</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn mr-2 mb-2" [ngClass]="selectedStyles.includes('iyengar') ? 'btn-yb' : 'btn-outline-secondary'" (click)="toggleClass('iyengar')">Iyengar</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn mb-2" [ngClass]="selectedStyles.includes('yin') ? 'btn-yb' : 'btn-outline-secondary'" (click)="toggleClass('yin')">Yin</button>
</div>
<div class="btn-toolbar special">
  <button type="button" class="btn mr-2 mb-2" [ngClass]="selectedStyles.includes('hatha') ? 'btn-yb' : 'btn-outline-secondary'" (click)="toggleClass('hatha')">Hatha</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn mr-2 mb-2" [ngClass]="selectedStyles.includes('kundalini') ? 'btn-yb' : 'btn-outline-secondary'" (click)="toggleClass('kundalini')">Kundalini</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn mb-2" [ngClass]="selectedStyles.includes('vinyasa') ? 'btn-yb' : 'btn-outline-secondary'" (click)="toggleClass('vinyasa')">Vinyasa</button>
</div>
<div class="btn-toolbar special">
  <button type="button" class="btn mr-2 mb-2" [ngClass]="selectedStyles.includes('power') ? 'btn-yb' : 'btn-outline-secondary'" (click)="toggleClass('power')">Power</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn mr-2 mb-2" [ngClass]="selectedStyles.includes('sivananda') ? 'btn-yb' : 'btn-outline-secondary'" (click)="toggleClass('sivananda')">Sivananda</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn mb-2" [ngClass]="selectedStyles.includes('restorative') ? 'btn-yb' : 'btn-outline-secondary'" (click)="toggleClass('restorative')">Restorative</button>
</div>
<div class="btn-toolbar special">
  <button type="button" class="btn mr-2 mb-2" [ngClass]="selectedStyles.includes('prenatal') ? 'btn-yb' : 'btn-outline-secondary'" (click)="toggleClass('prenatal')">Prenatal</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn mr-2 mb-2" [ngClass]="selectedStyles.includes('aerial') ? 'btn-yb' : 'btn-outline-secondary'" (click)="toggleClass('aerial')">Aerial</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn mb-2" [ngClass]="selectedStyles.includes('acro') ? 'btn-yb' : 'btn-outline-secondary'" (click)="toggleClass('acro')">Acro</button>
</div>
```

but I'm hardcoding in the styles in each button ex. 'vinyasa'

now I have a list of the items and I want to loop through them and construct the same thing (3 buttons in each btn-toolbar), something like this.

```html
<div *ngFor="let style of yogaStyles; let i = index">
  <div *ngFor="let number of [0,1,2,3]" class="btn-toolbar special">
    <button type="button" class="btn mr-2 mb-2" [ngClass]="selectedStyles.includes(style.id) ? 'btn-yb' : 'btn-outline-secondary'" (click)="toggleClass(style.id)">{{style.name}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I can't figure out the logic to create the button toolbar for 3 buttons at a time given my list of items 'yogaStyles'

any help would be appreciated

Comment: you've already have a condition `[ngClass]="selectedStyles.includes(style.id) ? 'btn-yb' : 'btn-outline-secondary'"` for the class....are you talking about `class="btn mr-2 mb-2"` in first 2 buttons and `class="btn mb-2"` in the last button?

Comment: well, if I understand your question, yes, those are classes I have in the buttons

Comment: you could have one more `[ngClass]="number===2?'mb-2':''"` and since you want 3 buttons inside `div.btn-toolbar.special` then move `*ngFor="let number of [0,1,2]"` on to your `<button>`

Comment: the problem I have with what I've done is that I have 4 toolbars for each of my yogaStyles. So there are way too many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two loops, you can use [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe)

```
<div class="btn-toolbar special" *ngFor="let row of [0,1,2]">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let style of yogaStyles
                   |slice:(row*3):(row+1)*3; let i = index">
        <button type="button" class="btn mr-2 mb-2" 
            [ngClass]="selectedStyles.includes(style.id) ? 'btn-yb' : 'btn-outline-secondary'">
           {{style.name}}
         </button>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Anohter option is used an array of arrays:

```
toolsBars=[
[
  {"id": "bikram","name": "bikram"},
  {"id": "iyengar","name": "iyengar"},
  {"id": "yin","name": "yin"}
],
[
  {"id": "hatha","name": "hatha"},
  {"id": "kundalini","name": "kundalini"},
  {"id": "vinyasa","name": "vinyasa"}
],
...
]
```

You can create the array "hardcode" or using forEach over the array

```
  yogaStyles = [
    { id: "bikram", name: "bikram" },
    { id: "iyengar", name: "iyengar" },
    { id: "yin", name: "yin" },
    { id: "hatha", name: "hatha" },
    { id: "kundalini", name: "kundalini" },
    { id: "vinyasa", name: "vinyasa" }
  ];
  toolsBar = []; //<--a new variable

  ngOnInit() {
    this.yogaStyles.forEach((x, index) => {
      if (index % 3 == 0) this.toolsBar.push([]);

      const items = this.toolsBar[this.toolsBar.length - 1];
      items.push({ id: x.id, name: x.name });
    });
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the help. It's going to take some to time to understand |slice:(row*3):(row+1)*3; let i = index"

Comment: slice:start:end, when row=0, you show slice:0,3 (0,1,2), when row=1, you slice:3,6 (3,4,5) and when row=2, you slice:6,9 (6,7,8), remember that the elemenst begings to 0, and in slice, the "end" is the last element that NOT show